# Importing shapefile into AutoCAD Map 3D?

Tags: shapefile, autocad-map

I'm trying to import shapefiles into a DWG using diferent layers names and during my web search I found this post. I know you did this 2 years ago but my problem is very similar and I wonder if you could help me. 
Basically I've got a shapefiles of pipelines and I want to use the attribute name to sort the features into different CAD levels in teh same layer.
I tried the import and although soem people say that "you can set the import to use data field" I can't see any option to do it and I'm really struggling. Any help appreciated.

I'm running on AutoCAD Map 3D 2010.

Comment: Have you seen this answer: http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/16263/187

Comment: Thank you!! This information was quite helpful. I am working with shapefiles downloaded from the FEMA website. Yvonne in AZ

Answer (score 4):

Try this to import .SHP to AutoCAD and separate distinct attributes onto different CAD layers...

In AutoCAD :

- Map-->Tools-->Import (or at the command line type MAPIMPORT)
- Select your .SHP (or .SHPs – you can bulk import)
- In the Drawing Layer column of the Import window, click the ellipses
  on the right-hand side of the box...

[image]

- Use the ‘Use data field for layer name’ option and select the
  attribute field from the .SHP that you want to layer the drawing.  In
  the image below, I’d get a CAD drawing with separate layers/linework
  for every unique county name in Minnesota

[image]

- Make sure you’ve got your coordinate systems set and if you want to
  retain the .SHP attribute information as Object Data in AutoCAD, use
  the Data column and set it to ‘Create object data’
- Click OK and you should be good to go...