# Export 3D Shapefile Polygon to DWG as Polygon

Tags: arcgis-desktop, 3d, export, dwg

I am looking for a way to export my 3D polygon shapefile to a .DWG polygon.  I have used the Conversion Tools - Export to CAD tool in ArcToolbox, but it will only export the polygon to line features.  Is there a setting or option that I am missing that will export as a polygon?

Thanks...

Comment: please fill in your question with more info

Comment: so is the issue reolved?

Comment: Its resolved from the stand point as I have the data I want, but not according to the specific question that was posted.  For me, I have want I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of AutoCAD?

A polygon in Autocad is not exactly what a polygon is in arc-desktop.
You don't just normally get a polygon fill.
A closed polyline would be considered a polygon.
[Are you sure it is exporting to "line" features?](http://docs.autodesk.com/ACD/2014/ENU/files/GUID-AEDF9E4E-97DF-4628-9D81-6C3512050878.htm)
use the list command and select one object.

Are there multiple objects (lines) making up one polygon?
is the object type lwpolyline in autocad?
Is it closed/open?
Are you wanting a polygon with fill?
In autocad there is an [edge and a fill (they both apply to the one polygon object.

You can display a polygon with one/ either/ or both](http://docs.autodesk.com/ACD/2014/ENU/files/GUID-889BB42E-7FF9-49CE-B2AD-F0EEE9027A45.htm).
Also it is very easy to convert objects from one to another type in autocad.

Lastley I always prferr atuocad map for this functionality. It does a much better job at it.  [See this question/answer for a similar process](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/16250/shapefile-attributes-to-autocad-annotation) that (if you have map3d) would give more usable results.

Comment: The version of AutoCAD isn't as important, as I am importing the CAD files into SketchUp.  SketchUp can read in DWG and DXF files. My issues is SketchUp reads the CAD file as lines.  But I have over come this issue with a SketchUp plugin:
     http://www.smustard.com/script/MakeFaces

Answer (score 1):

And here how to make it 3d;
you should create a field with a name "Elevation" and then calculate the values of the elevation or contour data to this field. After you have this data (shape or whatelse) just use "export to cad" tool on ArcToolbox. You will reach to the 3d dwg data.

If you don't have "elevation" field on your shape file you can never get the 3d data to your dwg file. you will see how I do in JPEG files attached. Have a good day.

[image]