# Exporting text to CAD

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, export, cad, text

I am using ArcMap 10.2 and have a shapefile with parcel data.  I have all of the polygons labeled with attribute text.  How do i export the text to CAD?

Comment: Have you looked [here](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/cad/exporting-attributes-as-cad-text.htm)?

Answer (score 0):

using the exporttoCAD command has the capability. however others report mixed results.  you can use the esri support website to view the process recommended by esri.  search google for [arcgis10.2 export to CAD](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00120000001n000000).
Also see [Question "Shapefile attributes to Autocad Annotation"](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/16250/shapefile-attributes-to-autocad-annotation/16263#16263)